# Show that if the set A is bounded then the set Bϵ(A) is bounded.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $A$ be a nonempty closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. For $\epsilon>0$, $B_{\epsilon}(A)= \left \{ x\in \mathbb{R}: d(x,A)<\epsilon) \right \}$.

a) Show that if the set $A$ is bounded then the set $B_{\epsilon}(A)$ is bounded.

b) Show that $B_{\epsilon}(A)$ is an open set and $A\sqsubseteq B_{\epsilon}(A)$.

c) $A = \bigcap  _{n\geq 1}B_{1/n}(A)$

My thoughts: for part a, if the set A is bounded then for every $a\in A$, $||a||<\vartheta $ Also for every $x$ in $B_{\epsilon}(A)$, $||x-a||<\epsilon$. Since $||x||-||a||\leq ||x-a||$, $||x||\leq \epsilon + \vartheta$. So $B_{\epsilon}(A)$ is bounded. ?

part b: Isn't $B_{\epsilon}(A)$ open by definition? If $\epsilon$ were equal to $0$, $B_{\epsilon}(A)$ would be equal to A. Since $\epsilon >0$, $A\sqsubseteq B_{\epsilon}(A)$. But I guess that's not a legitimate proof.

part c: This is intuitively very clear but I have no idea how to show it.

Answer (score 1):

**Part a** OK

**Part b** What is your definition of open? You have to prove that $B_\epsilon(A)$ is a neighborhood of all its points.

**Part c** To prove an equality between two sets $R = S$, you have to prove that $R \subset S$ and $S \subset R$. One direction is pretty clear from **part** b. For the other one consider a point $x \notin A$